# Why the button on the JFrame with background image cannot show properly

Tags: java, swing, jframe

i recently code a system homepage that include the background image. After i set the background, the button that i created cannot show properly. It just appear after i use the mouse and point to the buttons' location. Can someone teach me how to fix this problem? Your help are appreciated. The codes are as below:

public class HomePage extends JFrame{

```
private JPanel button = new JPanel();
private JButton time = new JButton("Bus Schedule");
private JButton reserve = new JButton("Booking");
private JButton info = new JButton("About Us");
Container con = getContentPane();


public HomePage(){

    setTitle("Bus Reservation System");
    setSize(650,500);
    setLocation(360,100);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setBackground();
    setButton();
}


public void setBackground(){

    JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:/User/Desktop/Assignment/bg.jpg"));
    con.add(background);
    background.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    con.add(button);

}


public void setButton(){

    Font but = new Font("Serif" , Font.ITALIC , 20);

    info.setFont(but);
    time.setFont(but);
    reserve.setFont(but);

    button.add(info);
    button.add(time);
    button.add(reserve);

    con.add(button);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple mistake (probably a typo?), you are setting the layout of the `JLabel`, you intended to set the layout of the `Container`. Do `con.setLayout(new FlowLayout());` instead of `background.setLayout(...)`

Also, I believe your path to the file is incorrect. For testing, just put the file in the project and do a path like "bg.jpg", if that works, we can verify this. For me that works. The reason I believe this is the issue is because you specify `C:/Users`, but then never give the folder for the specific User. A correct path would be `C:/Users/Your_name/Desktop/Assignment/bg.jpg`

I don't know for sure on that path part, since I'm not on your system. However, for me, if I run your code in my eclipse, this fixes it.

edit:
One last thing, the image isn't really going to be a "background" image with the current code because it will move the buttons underneath it instead of on top of it with the FlowLayout. You may want to use a different Layout.

Answer (score 1):

After you call `setVisible(true)`, if you perform certain actions, you must manually `validate()` or `revalidate()` your window.

It is simpler to just call `setVisible()` after you have initialized all of the desired settings and membership of the window.

```
/* setVisible(true); -- wrong place */
setResizable(false);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setBackground();
setButton();
setVisible(true); // proper place
```

Comment: This is correct, glad you mentioned it. But, does not seem to be the root of the problem, even with this change, the image file will not show. (I'm testing his exact code on my system). What did make it work was changing the path and setting the layout of the entire container.

Comment: @AshwinGupta Excellent point; I missed the layout of the JLabel instead of Container with just a visual inspection of the code.

Comment: Ty. I know how that is. I also missed it the first time (and the thing you pointed out). Thats why I tested it on my system, I didn't spot any errors and was curious why it wasn't working. Thats when I found the problem.

Comment: @AshwinGupta "It just appear after i use the mouse and point to the buttons' location" was a sure sign of a missing `validate()` or `revalidate()` issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all as already noted, all components should be added to the frame BEFORE invoking `setVisible(true)` on the `JFrame`.

```
JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:/User/Desktop/Assignment/bg.jpg"));
con.add(background);
background.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
con.add(button);
```

Based on the above code you are adding two components to the content pane so the hierarchy of your GUI looks like this:

```
- frame
    - content pane
        - background
        - button
```

It seems to me you want your GUI to look like this:

```
- frame
    - content pane
        - background
            - button
```

So your code should be:

```
JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:/User/Desktop/Assignment/bg.jpg"));
con.add(background);
background.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
//con.add(button);
background.add( button );
```